# setColorFilter applies to all buttons

Tags: java, android, button, custom-controls, android-custom-view

I have a class that extends button view, I use it to create custom shaped buttons like hex button and only respond to clicks on the actual button area and not the default rectangular shape of the view. That part works, however, I want also to be able to change the colors of the button without creating different drawables for each color so I created my button image in white with gray-scaled shadings and I use setColorFilter to set the colors which I read from the xml and it works great except that when the activity is started or restarted all buttons get the color of the last button (last created or clicked).
Clicking the buttons manually sets the correct color back but when changing the activity and coming back all buttons get the color of the last pressed button.

Here is where I initialize the color:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    // Set the button background and color
    updateButton(normalButton);
}

private void updateButton(Drawable background) {
    if (background == null) return;
    //Set button background
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        this.setBackground(background);
    } else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
    this.getBackground().setColorFilter(buttonColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    //this.setBackgroundColor(buttonColor);
}
```

The function `updateButton()` is also used in the `onTouch()` method to toggle the drawable between pressed and normal state. And that works and sets the correct color when pressing any of the buttons.

if I use `this.setBackgroundColor(buttonColor);` the coloring works find (but it overrides the image), however, `setColorFilter` is not working as i want.

#### Can someone help me with this?

Here is a link to the whole code ([link on github](https://github.com/fduraibi/FunWithArabic_Android/blob/0e6f0cf310c05741dd1856ed6670b44df6fd91a1/FunWithArabic_app/src/main/java/net/fadvisor/funwitharabic/ShapedButton.java))

[image]

This picture explains the problem, the one on the left is how it looks when it starts, while the one on the right is what it should be.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I need to mutate the drawable before applying the color filter.

```
myDrawable = myDrawable.mutate();
myDrawable.setColorFilter(buttonColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```